# Socketio implementation with FastApi and React

Tags: python, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

I have the following techstack

1. FastApi - backend
2. React - frontend

and want to implement socketio(not Websockets provided by FastApi). It lacks documentation in both FastApi and Socketio

Answer (score 13):

As needed we are using [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for backend socket server and on react we will be using [socket.io-client](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/).
After installation we need to setup a socket server.

**Backend Implementation**

```
# socket.py

def handle_connect(sid, environ):
    logger.info(f"Socket connected with sid {sid}")

class SocketManager:
    def __init__(self, origins: List[str]):
        self.server = socketio.AsyncServer(
            cors_allowed_origins=origins,
            async_mode="asgi",
            logger=True,
            engineio_logger=True,
        )
        self.app = socketio.ASGIApp(self.server)

    @property
    def on(self):
        return self.server.on

    @property
    def send(self):
        return self.server.send

    def mount_to(self, path: str, app: ASGIApp):
        app.mount(path, self.app)


socket_manager = SocketManager(settings.origins)
socket_manager.on("connect", handler=handle_connect)
```

Double check your cors origins. Also you can add other handlers as well using `socket_manager.on`.

```
#main.py

from socket import 

app = FastAPI(...)
socket_manager.mount_to("/ws", app)
```

**Frontend Implementation**
Basic code for integration is as simple as

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("ws://localhost:8000", {{ path: "/ws/socket.io/", transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] }});
socket.on("connect", () => { console.log("Connected", socket.id) }); 
socket.on("response", () => { console.log("Response", socket.id) });  
socket.on("message", data => { console.log(data) });
```

For my project i created a context for this as follows

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import { useToastContext } from './ToastContext';


export const SocketContext = createContext()


export const SocketProvider = ({ children, uri, options }) => {
    const [socketIo, setSocketIo] = useState()
    const { sendToast } = useToastContext();

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(uri, options);
        socket.on("connect", () => { console.log("Connected", socket.id) });
        socket.on("response", () => { console.log("Response", socket.id) });
        socket.on("message", data => { 
            sendToast(data)
        });
        setSocketIo(socket)
    }, [])

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socketIo}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useSocket = () => {
    return useContext(SocketContext)
}
```

Now to finally send a message from your server to client you can do

```
socket_manager.send("Hello World")
```

**Points worth noting**

- CORS origin should be exactly same if it is http://localhost:3000 from frontend then it should be http://localhost:3000 and **not http://localhost:3000/**. Look for the backslash
- Also the socketio documentation says `transports: ['websocket', 'polling']` is default but when i remove this. It gives me cors error. Documentation might be out of date.

Comment: In following your example I receive this error: cannot import name 'socket' from partially initialized module 'socket' :S

Comment: @MichaelPaccione i can't tell you anything without actually looking at your code.

Comment: I just got some help and am sorted out now

Comment: Thanks for all the details, it helps a lot!