# How to integrate socket io in fast-api?

Tags: fastapi

Case: Values are continuously updated in the database instead of API, socket is the best option,
but there is not much information related to socket io integration with fast-API(Python)

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/pyropy/fastapi-socketio? FastAPI has great WebSocket support built-in: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/ - no need to go through socketio in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socketio implementation with FastApi and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274482/socketio-implementation-with-fastapi-and-react)